# Using multi value parameters in measure group at SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mdx

I have a SSRS-report (2008 R2) which uses SSAS-cube as it's data source. At the report I have a data set with a MDX-query.

At the report I have defined parameters where some of them allow multiple value and at the MDX-query they're usually restricting the data set as follows:

```
    WHERE (
         STRTOMEMBER(@PARAM),
         STRTOSET(@MULTI_VALUE_PARAM)
    )
```

At one of the data sets i need to use the value parameter at calculated member like this:

```
    MEMBER [Measures].[MY_MEASURE] AS (
        [Measures].[MEASURE_FROM_MY_CUBE],
        STRTOSET(@MULTI_VALUE_PARAM)
    )
```

This doesn't work and I don't know why?

If I change the parameter, that it doesn't allow multiple values, and use it like this:

```
    MEMBER [Measures].[MY_MEASURE] AS (
        [Measures].[MEASURE_FROM_MY_CUBE],
        STRTOMEMBER(@MULTI_VALUE_PARAM)
    )
```

it works

So it seems I can't restrict the measure with multi value parameter. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
MEMBER [Measures].[MY_MEASURE] AS Aggregate(
    STRTOSET(@MULTI_VALUE_PARAM),
    [Measures].[MEASURE_FROM_MY_CUBE],
)
```

The syntax `( [Measures].[MEASURE_FROM_MY_CUBE], <something> )` that you use defines a tuple in MDX, and that may only contain a single member from each hierarchy. And a set is not a member. The `Aggregate` MDX function takes a set as first parameter, and an expression as the second, and then aggregates the set according to the cube definition - which in most cases is summing, but might be different for some measures.

Comment: That makes sense. It's a bit difficult to see the actual problem because the member only gets a null value, no actual errors. I've now tried:

          MEMBER [Measures].[MY_MEASURE] AS Aggregate(
              SUM(STRTOSET(@MULTI_VALUE_PARAM),
              [Measures].[MEASURE_FROM_MY_CUBE])
          )

but I still get only null values. 

In this case @MULTI_VALUE_PARAM contains user. MEASURE_FROM_MY_CUBE is a numeric value which at some cases should be restricted/filtered by the selected users.

Comment: You should leave off the `sum()`, as `Aggregate()` will take care of the summing. Alternatively, if you only have summable measures, you could replace `Aggregate` with `Sum`. But you should never use both.